# Where to put custom global functions in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to add implementation of array_column() for CakePHP app that is currently running on PHP 5.3 (array_column() has been introduced in PHP 5.5). What would be the best method of doing it without touching core files?

**Please note that I don't want to use helper, I really want to define global function.**

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp

Comment: Thank you, I've read the documentation but somehow I didn't catch it. In my defense - I wouldn't expect to find it in 'Configuration/Bootstrapping' section of the book.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't want to write a helper there are a few places where you can put global functions. If you're going to use the functions only in your controllers the best place is the AppController. In a similar way you could use the AppModel class for model functions and for the views you could put them within a layout.
But if you want to use the functions across the entire application, I would recommend putting them inside the app/Config/bootstrap.php file.

Comment: Is there any Citation from CakePHP?

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu As far as i know, no, just personal experience